# Run Jupyter lab container on given virtualenv

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to use a Jupyter lab inside the virtualenv on a Docker container.
I tried to run Jupyter lab container inside the virtualenv, but cannot because $PATH variable is wrong.

Background: 
I'm using a kind of hpc cluster, so we don't have much permissions.
I must run Jupyter lab on a read-only docker container.
My home and work directories are mounted.
But non-root users cannot build any new container images
(I am planning to propose this solution to admin).

Requirements:
I want to install new packages that is not provided on the read-only container.
And I want to install new packages to the specified location.

So I want to create a Docker image that runs Jupyter lab in the virtualenv if the $VENV_PATH environment variable is given.

I created a Dockerfile and a script based on [jupyter/datascience-notebook image on DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/dockerfile).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook

USER $NB_UID
COPY start-venv-notebook.sh /usr/local/bin/
CMD ["start-venv-notebook.sh"]
```

start-venv-notebook.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [[ ! -z "${VENV_PATH}" ]]; then
    abspath=$(realpath "${VENV_PATH}")
    if [ ! -e "${abspath}" ]; then
        # create venv
        python -m venv "${abspath}"
    fi
    # activate venv
    export VIRTUAL_ENV=$abspath
    export PATH="$abspath/bin:$PATH"
fi

# exec original CMD
exec /usr/local/bin/start-notebook.sh "$@"
```

And I want to use this container like this:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -e VENV_PATH=testvenv -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes venvjupyterlab
```

However, when I run this container, it does not run in the virtualenv.
I think the cause is from $PATH. 
/opt/conda/bin is added from somewhere. I cannot find the point.

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/conda/bin:/home/jovyan/testvenv/bin:/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Plsease give me some help or tell me other solutions.
Thanks.

Comment: You can’t generally run a Python virtual environment in another context: it has things like hard-coded filesystem paths and dependencies on a specific real Python.  If you have a virtual environment already, just use it; don’t try to transplant it into Docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze I know a Python virtual environment holds their interpreter paths.
To install some packages selected by the users on read-only container, I think to give a project's virtualenv path is the best solution.
Just I want to use the virtualenv thet is prepared for each project as the local installation target of the packages.
I do not reuse in another container.